# DateTime from SA to PBI only show date in some diagrams

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

I am sending some data including a datetime field from Stream Analytics to PowerBi. Line diagrams draw correctly with both date and time shown but other diagrams like tables and filters only show year-month-date and not hour-minute-second parts of date time.
Is it possible to format date time fields in visualization somehow?
And will you be introducing Max Min operations on date time fields in powerbi as you have for number fields?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and split it up before sending to PBI. That way you can add them in separately or grouped.

```
concat(
cast( datepart(yy,DateAdd(Hour,11,System.Timestamp)) as nvarchar(max)),
'/',
cast( datepart(mm,DateAdd(Hour,11,System.Timestamp)) as nvarchar(max)),
'/',
cast( datepart(dd,DateAdd(Hour,11,System.Timestamp)) as nvarchar(max))) [Date],
concat(
cast( datepart(hh,DateAdd(Hour,11,System.Timestamp)) as nvarchar(max)),
':',
cast( datepart(ss,DateAdd(Hour,11,System.Timestamp)) as nvarchar(max))) [Time],
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: Sure but than it is string and sorting order might change a bit if you miss leading zeros for one digit date/months.